# Is Seq.append O(1) time and space?

Tags: f#, time-complexity, seq

What is the complexity for Seq.append? Is it O(1) time and space?

I might add that (a) I should certainly hope so, and (b) I failed to google my way to complexity bounds for `Seq` module members. If someone know of such, I'd love to have a link to it.

EDIT. I did check the source code before asking. The implementation is [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L414), which will make you look, eventually, at [this function](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L389), the implementation of which is not immediately accessible to me, and the comments before which puzzles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is O(1) because it basically just create a new object that encapsulates the two original sequences.

See source code [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs)

Comment: That said, if you create a new object that encapsulates the two original sequences, and then keep doing that repeatedly to build up a large sequence, actually iterating the resulting franken-sequence is not going to perform very well.